# How to convert english numbers inside a string to Persian/Arabic numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, arabic, farsi

I have an english string that may or may not have numbers. But i want those numbers to be printed on screen as Persian numbers.

For example if `NSString *foo = @"a string with numbers 1 2 3;"`

then output should be `a string with numbers ۱۲۳`

The code I'm using right now is :

```
-(NSString *)convertEnNumberToFarsi:(NSString *) number{
    NSString *text;
    NSDecimalNumber *someNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:number];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa"];
   [formatter setLocale:gbLocale];
   text = [formatter stringFromNumber:someNumber];
   return text;
}
```

This method only converts a string that is only in numbers, but as mentioned above i want to convert any string that may or may not have numbers in it.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple way:

```
NSDictionary *numbersDictionary = @{@"1" : @"۱", @"2" : @"۲", @"3" : @"۳", @"4" : @"۴", @"5" : @"۵", @"6" : @"۶", @"7" : @"۷", @"8" : @"۸", @"9" : @"۹",@"0" : @"٠"};
for (NSString *key in numbersDictionary) {
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:key withString:numbersDictionary[key]];
}
```

Other solution more flexible with locale:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  NSNumber *num = @(i);
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:num.stringValue withString:[formatter stringFromNumber:num]];
}
```

*Note: this code wrote without IDE, it can be with syntax errors.*

Answer (score 10):

In swift 3:

```
func convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String)->String{
    let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num)!)
    let format = NumberFormatter()
    format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    let faNumber = format.string(from: number)

    return faNumber!
}
```

Check before force unwrap to prevent crash.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3:**

However other answers are correct, there is a little problem in converting `String` to `Int`.

Converting a `String` to `Int` removes left zeros which is not good (Specially in converting cell phones and national Ids). To avoid this problem I prefer replacing each English number to Persian.

```
static func convertToPersian(text : String)-> String {
    let numbersDictionary : Dictionary = ["0" : "۰","1" : "۱", "2" : "۲", "3" : "۳", "4" : "۴", "5" : "۵", "6" : "۶", "7" : "۷", "8" : "۸", "9" : "۹"]
    var str : String = text

    for (key,value) in numbersDictionary {
        str =  str.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
    }

    return str
}
```

This method can also be used to replace numbers within text and its not necessary to have a pure number to convert to Persian.

Answer (score 2):

convert number to any locale

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
if let localized = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: comp.0)) {
   return "\(localized)"
}
```

example:

> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 0)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٠"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 1)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "١"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 2)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٢"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 3)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٣"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 4)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٤"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 5)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٥"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 6)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٦"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 7)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٧"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 8)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٨"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 9)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "٩"
>
> (lldb) po formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 10)) ▿
>   Optional
>     - some : "١٠"

Answer (score 2):

## From Any language, To Any Language

---

You can convert digits in any language to any other like:

```
"سلام 12345".convertedDigitsToLocale(Locale(identifier: "FA")) /* سلام ۱۲۳۴۵ */
"Hello ۱۲۳۴۵".convertedDigitsToLocale(Locale(identifier: "EN")) /* Hello 12345 */
```

---

## The extension:

with the following extension:

```
extension String {
    private static let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    func clippingCharacters(in characterSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        components(separatedBy: characterSet).joined()
    }

    func convertedDigitsToLocale(_ locale: Locale = .current) -> String {
        let digits = Set(clippingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted))
        guard !digits.isEmpty else { return self }

        Self.formatter.locale = locale
        let maps: [(original: String, converted: String)] = digits.map {
            let original = String($0)
            guard let digit = Self.formatter.number(from: String($0)) else {
                assertionFailure("Can not convert to number from: \(original)")
                return (original, original)
            }
            guard let localized = Self.formatter.string(from: digit) else {
                assertionFailure("Can not convert to string from: \(digit)")
                return (original, original)
            }
            return (original, localized)
        }

        var converted = self
        for map in maps { converted = converted.replacingOccurrences(of: map.original, with: map.converted) }
        return converted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5

```
func getNumerals(num: Int) -> String {
    if getLanguage() == "ar" // You can set locale of your language
    {  
        let number = NSNumber(value: num)
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar") // You can set locale of your language
        let formatedNumber = format.string(from: number)
        return formatedNumber!
    } else {
        return "\(num)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no other way than replacing them.

e.g.:

```
str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"۰"];
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *)convertNumToPersian:(NSString *)EnglishNumString
{
    if ( [EnglishNumString isEqual:[NSNull null]] )
        return @"";

    NSString *myString = [EnglishNumString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@"۱"];
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"2" withString:@"۲"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3" withString:@"۳"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"4" withString:@"۴"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"5" withString:@"۵"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"6" withString:@"۶"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"7" withString:@"۷"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"8" withString:@"۸"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"9" withString:@"۹"];
    myString =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"۰"];
    return myString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/**
     * In this function convert Arabic number to English number.
     * @sample stringValue : Pass String value.
     */

```
fun numberArabicToEnglish(stringValue: String): String {
    val value = stringValue
        .replace("١", "1")
        .replace("٢", "2")
        .replace("٣", "3")
        .replace("٤", "4")
        .replace("٥", "5")
        .replace("٦", "6")
        .replace("٧", "7")
        .replace("٨", "8")
        .replace("٩", "9")
        .replace("٠", "0")
    return value
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 and newer**

if you want to make a subclass of UILabel:

```
class LocalizedNumbersLabel: UILabel {

override var text: String? {
    didSet {
        if let text = text {
            let numbersDictionary : Dictionary = ["0" : "۰","1" : "۱", "2" : "۲", "3" : "۳", "4" : "۴", "5" : "۵", "6" : "۶", "7" : "۷", "8" : "۸", "9" : "۹", "." : ","]
            var str = text

            for (key,value) in numbersDictionary {
                str =  str.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
            }
            if(str != self.text){
                self.text = str
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

}