# The NSFormatter for Converting English Number to persian or arabic Number in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, number-formatting, nsformatter

I read the similar questions here and Write this method in my app

```
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    func convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String)->String{
        let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num)!)
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        let faNumber = format.string(from: number)

        return faNumber!


    }
```

I didn't get Error But I didn't get the result too!

my Number code is this :

```
let checkNumber = Home2ViewController().customtitle.count
    personalCustom.text = ("\(checkNumber)")
```

I used another Number in another View Controller that works But I want to show this Number in persian or arabic number format not in English format

Comment: see this my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43841057/3901620

Comment: thanks This was useful

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479225

Comment: Where are you calling `convertEngNumToPersianNum`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
func convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String)->String{
        //let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num)!)
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR") 
        let number =   format.number(from: num)
        let faNumber = format.string(from: number!)
        return faNumber!

    }
```

**OR repalce with your line**

```
        let number =   format.number(from: num)
    let faNumber = format.string(from: number!)
```

Comment: please help me to find similar question answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627982/how-to-use-persian-numbers-in-uitextfield-in-swift-3

Comment: can you elaborate what is your requirement .

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like,

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.current   // you can specify locale that you want
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true



    let number = formatter.number(from: "١٠.٠٠")

    print(number ?? "")
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert to Arabic while keeping the leading zeros

```
func convertToArDigits(_ digits: String) -> String {
            // We need a CFMutableString and a CFRange:
            let cfstr = NSMutableString(string: digits) as CFMutableString
            var range = CFRange(location: 0, length: CFStringGetLength(cfstr))
            // Do the transliteration (this mutates `cfstr`):
            CFStringTransform(cfstr, &range, kCFStringTransformLatinArabic, false)
            // Convert result back to a Swift string:
            return (cfstr as String)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   extension String {
public var faToEnDigits : String {
    let farsiNumbers = ["٠": "0","١": "1","٢": "2","٣": "3","٤": "4","٥": "5","٦": "6","٧": "7","٨": "8","٩": "9"]
    var txt = self
    farsiNumbers.map { txt = txt.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1)}
    return txt
}
public var enToFaDigits : String {
    let englishNumbers = ["0": "۰","1": "۱","2": "۲","3": "۳","4": "۴","5": "۵","6": "۶","7": "۷","8": "۸","9": "۹"]
    var txt = self
    englishNumbers.map { txt = txt.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1)}
    return txt
}
}
```

Comment: The digits you have used in your third line (`faToEnDigits`), are Arabic digits, not Persian, where those in `enToFaDigits` are actually Persian. This creates inconsistency in your code and conversion process.

Comment: @Neeku thanks for your comment but about digits Persian history is older than Arabic and math move from Persian empire to Arabic region.

Comment: So, what’s your point? “۴۵۶” vs. “٤٥٦” are 6 different unicode characters, the former three are for fa_IR, where the latter are for ar_AR. This has nothing to do to Persian Empire. In fact they used cuneiform which is an extinct ancient language.

Comment: @Neeku 6 has two form(۶ and ٦) in IR-FA and i put both of them to show there aren't different between them

Comment: Well, that is exactly the mistake I'm attempting to point out. They *are* indeed different. The former is U+06F6, the latter is U+0666. You can read more about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Deviations_from_the_Arabic_script . You can also google them (or any other similar string like ی ک vs. ي ك in double quotations to see the different search results. (كيك كي vs. کیک کی) are actually different. This misuse of wrong characters impacts things like hashtag trends, etc.